# parsing tsv file starting with quotation mark

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried to parse a TSV file which contains two columns, some lines only contain quotation mark. Is there a way to parse them as separate lines using python without adding '\' before the quotation mark?

```
presents    O
it    O
in    O
"   O
classical   O
"   O
principles  O
on  O
which   O
'   O
the O
operation   O
was O
'   O
conceived   O
.   O
```

I've tried code like

```
with open("sample.tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t")
    for line in tsvreader:
        print (line)
```

The result for the three lines are incorrect

```
"   O
classical   O
"   O
```

Current result is

```
['\tO\nclassical\tO\n', 'O']
```

I want the result to be

```
['"', 'O']
['classical', 'O']
['"', 'O']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `csv.reader` to ignore quote characters by adding `quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE` when you create the instance:

```
import csv
with open("sample.tsv") as tsvfile:
    tsvreader = csv.reader(tsvfile, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for line in tsvreader:
        print (line)
```

Output (for the lines with quotes):

```
['"', 'O']
['classical', 'O']
['"', 'O']
```

The documentation for the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) explains that [`csv.QUOTE_NONE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE) "instructs `reader` to perform no special processing on quote characters."